# Get bitmap from assests then load it into the background 

Tags: android, background, bitmap, imageview

Hey Everyone I have had a lot of help here in the past and was wondering if you guys could help me out with something.

I would like to load a bitmap from the assets and then add it to the background of a linear layout image view that i created in code. I know how to do this with an xml layout file but in this case i need to do it in code. I have this so far and it works with an .xml layout but when I try to create the linear layout and ImageView in code the image is not showing up. Is there something i am overlooking or doing wrong. 
here is the code I got

```
ImageView backgroundPainting = new ImageView(this);
    backgroundPainting.setAdjustViewBounds(true);


    LinearLayout rel = new LinearLayout(this);
//    RelativeLayout backgroundPaintingRL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    //lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.ButtonRecalculate);
    //lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    rel.addView(backgroundPainting, lp);


    // backgroundPainting = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backgroundPainting2);
     getArtist = levelSelect.getArtistNameSelected();
     getLevel = level.getLevelSelected() ;

     String imagePath = "artists-images/"+getArtist + getLevel+".jpg";
     try { // Get reference to AssetManager
         AssetManager mngr = getAssets();
         // Create an input stream to read from the asset folder
            InputStream ins = mngr.open(imagePath);

            // Convert the input stream into a bitmap
            levelBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ins);
            backgroundPainting.setImageBitmap(levelBitmap);
      } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(levelView.this, "couldn't set image to background", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
```

Please Help thnx,

Pengume

Comment: Does your toast shows up while running?

Comment: if it doesn't, are you calling `setContentView(rel)`?

Comment: yes my toast well appear. I have a custom GamePanel that I am setting as the content view, but it is a different class.

Comment: please post the exception then, you'll find it in the LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first create one linear layout in your xml file. 
And then access that layout in your code.

```
LinearLayout linearMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearmainLayout);
```

Then you try below thing by adding this two lines at the last after setting bitmap image in backgroundPainting

```
rel.addView(backgroundPainting, lp);

linearMain.addView(rel);
```

or  you can try this way

```
setContentView(rel);
```

and write one line  at the last after setting bitmap image in backgroundPainting

```
rel.addView(backgroundPainting, lp);
```

Comment: so your saying I can not just construct a new LinearLayout in code and then add an Image view to that without first having an xml file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this view rel to its parent view the view is being created  but not added

Answer (score 0):

Just use `setContentView(rel);` after creating your `LinearLayout`